# Why is the Firefox webkitdirectory implementation so slow reading from DVD/CD?

Tags: performance, firefox, directory, cd, dvd

Im working on a file upload service using HTML5. In the use case the user wants to upload whole directory, which he receives in form of a CD/DVD.

Reading directories is possible in Chrome using the

> webkitdirectory | mozwebkitdirectory | directory

attribute.

Mozilla Firefox has adapted this feature this August, in Version 55.
Reading from Hardisk, this feature works great on Chrome, and still alright, even though a little slower, on Firefox.

But as soon as the user picks a CD/DVD path, or a directory which is located on the CD/DVD, Firefox becomes very slow and hangs more often than not.

Here is a simple snippet, which loads a directory, iterates over the file meta data, and loads one file into memory to show its size.

```js
document.getElementById("filepicker").addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  let output = document.getElementById("listing");
  let files = event.target.files;
  let fileReader = new FileReader();

  let start = new Date().getTime();
  for (let i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    let item = document.createElement("li");
    item.innerHTML = files[i].webkitRelativePath;
    output.appendChild(item);
  };
  
  console.log("Time used for iterating over file meta: " + (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000 + "s");
  
 
  
  fileReader.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
          console.log("File Loaded");
          console.log("Time for loading Single File into memory: " + (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000 + "s");
          let blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(evt.target.result)], {type: "arraybuffer"});
          console.log("Blob Size is: " + blob.size); //To show that file is read to memory.
          }, false);

   console.log("START LOADING FILE");
   start = new Date().getTime();
   fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);

}, false);
```

```html
<div>
  Select Directory:
  <input id=filepicker type="file" webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory directory multiple>   
<div>

<div id=listing></div>
```

You can try for yourself, maybe the error depends just on my CD/DVD drive.
The questions I have are:

- Do you have similar problems loading from CD/DVD drive?
- Is this a known error in the Firefox webkitdirectory implementation?
- Am I doing something wrong, is there another way to get Filenames and load files into memory ?

If you have similar problems I might fill an Issue report to Mozilla.

Comment: I filed a bug report. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1409646